# How to make modals with different content

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I want to make a website (done). Then I´m adding at least 30 buttons, and when you press the first button, a simple modal comes up with the ability to close, but when you press the second button, the same thing happens! It's just another content.

Let me try to tell you this in my bad programming language.

```
<div class="button" id="modal1">1</div>
```

if `pressed = "modal1"` opens.

---

```
<div class="button" id="modal2">2</div>
```

îf `pressed = "modal2"` opens with different content.

I would add some code, but I haven´t got any longer than the Bootstrap: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal&stacked=h

Comment: try like this https://jsfiddle.net/jgx9LsjL/1/ but i will strongly suggest to read about html and modal first as this is a very basic thing

Answer (score 0):

If you use Bootstrap modal u need just to change data-target and crate modals for all buttons.

Comment: i dont have such skills, may you please help me? :)

Answer (score 0):

just check this link http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp it explain how modal works. You must have data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" in item you click to open modal and you need mention "#myModal" as id of the target modal, use different id to open different modal.

Answer (score 0):

You can see my three modals, like i said you just need to change `data-target="#myModal1" and id="myModal1"`
`https://jsfiddle.net/milanpanin/b2pyb6Lq/

Answer (score 0):

Using the sample you linked, I copied and pasted the first model div to a second and made minor changes so you can see the difference when clicking on the buttons.
I then copied and pasted the button, and changed the data-target attribute in the second button to match the div I added.

```
        <div class="container">
          <h2>Modal Example</h2>
          <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->

            <!-- data-target in the first button matches the id of the first div below -->
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
        <!-- the second button data-target matches the id of thj e second div below -->
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Open Modal</button>
          <!-- Modal -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

              <!-- Modal content-->
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- this is copied from the first div, given its own id -->
           <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

              <!-- Modal content-->
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header 2</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <p>Some text in the modal. model 2</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```